# How to insert a u32 into a u8 array in Zig?

Tags: zig

I have a `u8` buffer that stores a series of values including the RGB components from two u32 values (of which only 24 bits are used).

I'm currently using bitwise operations to extract the individual components, then using `@truncate` to drop the precision so they'll fit.

```
var buffer = [_]u8{0} ** max_buffer_size;
const fg = 0xAABBCC;
const bg = 0xAABBCC;

// ...

buffer[idx + 2] = @truncate(u8, fg & 0xFF);
buffer[idx + 3] = @truncate(u8, fg >> 8 & 0xFF);
buffer[idx + 4] = @truncate(u8, fg >> 16 & 0xFF);
buffer[idx + 5] = @truncate(u8, bg & 0xFF);
buffer[idx + 6] = @truncate(u8, bg >> 8 & 0xFF);
buffer[idx + 7] = @truncate(u8, bg >> 16 & 0xFF);
```

Is there a way to insert the `u32` values directly into this memory instead without needing to unpack the values?

```
// this (obviously) doesn't work (expecting a u8, getting a u32)
buffer[idx + 2] = fg;
```

Comment: use `@bitCast`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `writeIntNative` or other variants ([check `std.mem` source code](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.10.0/lib/std/mem.zig#L1560)) to do this.

E.g.

```
std.mem.writeIntNative(u32, buffer[idx..][0..@sizeOf(u32)], fg);
```